# Android: How to set both staticHeaders and dynamic Headers in same service call? Is this possible?

Tags: android, android-studio, retrofit, retrofit2

I have got a scenario like need to pass one header as parameter

```
@GET("mobile/userProfile")
Observable<ProfileDetail> getImageUrlDetail(@Header("contentType") String contentType,
                                              @Query("pictureName") String fileName);
```

and also I need to set Authorization and X-API key.

So I have created a custom Intercepter and adding Authorization and X-API key in this interceptor.

But only one header is working either static or dynamic header. Both headers should be set into OkHttpClient. Otherwise, I will receive 400 bad request.

```
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new okhttp3.OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // 30 seconds Connection Timeout
                .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // 60 seconds Read Timeout
                .addInterceptor(interceptor)
                .addInterceptor(logging)
                .build();
```

the weird scenario is If add my custom interceptor first and then logging interceptor. It gives custom interceptor's HEADERS in logcat.
If I switch the lines,
                **.addInterceptor(logging)
                .addInterceptor(interceptor)**
Then I'm getting @Header in logcat, which is passing as param.

I want to set both headers to API call get 200 response.

Suggestion and solutions are most welcome.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of things about your code and question. Let me try and help you with all of them the best I can.

First

> the weird scenario is If add my custom interceptor first and then logging interceptor. It gives custom interceptor's HEADERS in logcat. If I switch the lines, .addInterceptor(logging) .addInterceptor(interceptor) Then I'm getting @Header in logcat, which is passing as param.

If I get it right then that's 100% expected and it's how it works. Interceptors work like a chain, so when you do

```
.addInterceptor(interceptor)
.addInterceptor(logging)
```

Then it will run first `interceptor`, which I guess adds the api key and then it will run the `logging` interceptor, which will log all the headers added so far to the request. The `@Header` is added by retrofit, not by `OkHttp`, so it should be there even if you don't have any interceptor and it will be there before the `okhttp` interceptors get a chance to kick in.

If you switch it around:

```
.addInterceptor(logging)
.addInterceptor(interceptor)
```

Then you'll log first - no api key header has been added yet - and then you add the api key header. That's why in log cat you don't see your api key header added if you do it like that, but you do see the `@Header`. As a rule of thumb, always put the logging last in the chain.

In both scenarios, both headers should be added to the final request regardless of the order of the interceptors. If this is not the case, then there's something else on the way messing up the headers.

Now onto the static vs. dynamic headers. To my best of knowledge these should work pretty well together. The thing I'm guessing it's not working is the fact you have `@Header("contentType")` - notice how you've wrote `contentType`? It should be `content-type` if I understand this [standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) correctly. So it should work if you change it to `@Header("Content-Type")`.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, Fred. Actually, The **Header** key which we received from the service team is `"contentType"` not `"Content-Type"`. Whatever Let me try the scenario you said.